# Is there an extension or other way to split up my Thunderbird inbox into two sections?

Tags: thunderbird

I'm looking for a way to make two or more separate sections *inside* of my inbox (not creating folders or starring).

So maybe a section for "Mailing list emails" one for "Waiting on other people" - that sort of thing. This could make my inbox be significantly less daunting.

Gmail has priority inbox - so kind of like that, with the ability to move things in between sections based on *customizable* things, not necessarily priority.

**Revised Description:**
Ok - I'm looking for one of two things: 1) A way to split an inbox into sections where I can drag/drop between the sections to assign a different customizable 'tag' to the message OR 2) A way to tag messages sort of like Message Filter looks like it would do (and then allow me to sort them). #1 is preferable. This would make it so I could put messages of one type (say from a mailing list) in a category so they're not in the way of the other 40-50 messages I actually want to deal with

Comment: I posted a bounty. We'll see if we get some more ideas. You may be asked to add details to your question. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

The only option I've used is the built in message filters. You can find that under the Tools menu. You can filter them by email addresses and contents of the subject line and apply actions automatically to the message. Actions like adding tags or moving to a specific folder.

If you don't want to use the folder structure, I believe your only option to use the tags. You could have all items that are from a certain list of emails get tagged as "work", anything referencing algebra as "class", etc. Then you could do a query for all the messages that have that tag.

**Edited to Add:** The only add-on I've found (but haven't used) is [MessageFilter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/3376/), which uses "multi-level bayesian filtering..." but the reviews have been mixed so YMMV.

Comment: I meant more in the way of a plugin - I know the functionality isn't built into thunderbird, but figured someone else somewhere might also want it and has made something already

Comment: @dfree: thanks for pointing out your interest in plugins. (I added a bit to my answer in response.) You may want to rephrase your question to explicitly say add-on/extension.

Comment: oh that's a good find, thank you yhw42. the problem is that it's not compatible with thunderbird 3.0.

i do remember coming across a way to edit the xpi and change the "version number" in the file itself, but now I can't find how to do it. any ideas?

Comment: I found a description on how to do that [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_an_add-on_to_change_its_compatibility), but I've never done that before. Good luck!

Comment: Ok - the xpi editor solution works (I knew it had to do with changing the extension of the .xpi); -- however the extension itself is a tool for channeling mail INTO folders automatically -- so not quite what I'm going for as far as *creating customizable inbox sections* or *tags* to make the inbox more manageable. Any other ideas?

Comment: What is it exactly you are looking for? sub tagging inside your inbox? A custom view of the inbox with certain tags grouped/next to each other? You could try to edit your question to describe more fully what outcome your are trying to achieve. I'm out of ideas with what I've got. :)

Comment: Ok - I'm looking for one of two things:

1) A way to split an inbox into sections where I can drag/drop between the sections to assign a different customizable 'tag' to the message

OR

2) A way to tag messages sort of like Message Filter looks like it would do (and then allow me to sort them). #1 is preferable.

This would make it so I could put messages of one type (say from a mailing list) in a category so they're not in the way of the other 40-50 messages I actually want to deal with. Does that make sense?

Comment: I've got nothing right now. Edit the last comment back into your question and change the title to include "extension" and state what you want as clearly as you can. That should bump your question back to the front page and get some more visibility. More eyes on this couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

Thunderbird has a mechanism to tag/label email which might be suitable, without using any extension.
From [mozillaZine Tags](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Tags) :

> Tags are descriptive, colored text
>   assigned to messages, used to organize
>   and group messages. Tags can be
>   manually assigned by keyboard, or by
>   message filters.
>
> View -> Sort by -> Tags can sort the
>   messages in a folder based on the tag.
>   View -> Messages -> Tags can be used
>   to display just the messages with the
>   selected tag. The View list box has a
>   similar menu command. You can also
>   create a custom view using View ->
>   Messages -> Customize that displays
>   just the messages with the desired
>   tags. Using tags with [saved searches](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_:_FAQs_:_Saved_Search)
>   can be very useful.

See [Mozilla Thunderbird Tips and Tricks](http://legroom.net/howto/thunderbird) for way of customizing the look of tagged/labelled messages. See also [How to use Thunderbird to get things done](http://www.ehow.com/how_4756668_use-thunderbird-things-done.html) how to create your own tags.

Tags can be assigned by [Message Filters](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Filters_%28Thunderbird%29). The following shows creating a filter in Thunderbird 2:

[image]

Here are some extensions that work with tags:

[Tag Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/4970/)

> This extension adds new toolbar and
>   display the tags you have created as
>   toggle buttons; the added toolbar is
>   called "Tag Toolbar" and the space for
>   showing tags is called "Tag Bar". You
>   can attach/remove tags to/from the
>   selected messages. The tag buttons'
>   states are changed automatically, so
>   you can easily know what tags are
>   attached to the message. Moreover, you
>   can filter the tags to be displayed by
>   categorizing tags. You can create and
>   change category from the listbox on
>   Tag Bar.

[image]

[Tag Dialog](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/4984/)

> Easily add or create tags.

[image]

Comment: Wow, great find harrymc. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Not surprising that t-bird would have this functionality available. It has everything I'm looking for **EXCEPT** one crucial feature: The ability to then have certain tags automatically sort to the top or bottom of the inbox based on classification.

Does that make sense? That way I could change a tag to "mailing lists" or "waiting on someone else" and have it automatically go to the bottom of my inbox - or classify something as "urgent follow up" and have it go to the top

Comment: A different section for those classifications would be great, but less essential imo

Comment: You can sort by tags. You can then also group by tags, which is like having separate sub-folders (View | Sort by | Grouped By Sort).

Comment: This is close, but not 100% of the way there - t-bird does know to sort based on date *after* sorting by tag which is good, but there are two problems with doing it this way. 1) **all the tags** must be together - i.e. you can't have one set of tags go on top of the rest of an unclassified inbox and one set of tags go below it. 2) the tags don't process in real-time, so you'd have to click out of the folder and come back to it to see your classifications update

Comment: Indeed they don't re-sort immediately. You can launch a query in the TB forums to ensure that this isn't simply a bug.

Comment: either way, from a functionality standpoint my 1st point is what seems more useful. without a fix for that, the main goal of making the inbox less daunting is still somewhat lost

Comment: I have added above some extensions that make easier working with tags. I also found out that one can create one's own tags (Options -> Display -> Tags).

Comment: Ok - 'tag toolbar' is nice, but 'tag dialogue' seems unnecessary with the functionality that's already in t-bird - you can tag messages by simply pressing 1, 2, etc... these are good but still don't address the concern that **tags cannot be split up within the inbox.** I want to have the ability to have one set of tags appear on top of my inbox, while another set of tags appears at the bottom. Does that make sense?

Comment: The tags appear on top of the sort order, but nothing stops you from using a "normal" tag that has no color, together with a default message filter that tags everything with it. That way you can position the "normal" messages anywhere you like using Options -> Tabs.

Comment: Oh i see what you're saying - classify ALL my emails as some status, and then make the tags that I want on top of the inbox be flagged with a tag alphabetically before the 'default' tag and vice-versa for emails that i want below. not so eloquent but it could work. Is there a way to automatically un-tag messages that would have the 'default' tag as i sort them into folders? Also is there a way to re-sort the inbox in-real time to account for newly tagged messages?

Comment: (1) Automatically un-tag: Doesn't seem to exist. Easy enough to select-all and untag. (2) Re-sort inbox in real-time has never worked for me in TB, but restricting the view should do it. Saved searches is another way to customize the display.

Comment: Nono for automatically untagging I meant as one is moving a message to a folder I would like it to get automatically untagged from your proposed 'default' tag. Otherwise, the user has to manually clear the tag of EACH message prior to sorting it... Thanks a lot for trying. This solution is ok, but compromises a good portion of the intended functionality of my idea. Definitely better than nothing though.

Comment: @harry: I'm awarding the bounty before I forget... Thanks for all your help and keeping up with the feedback!  @dfree I hope you found something useful, even if it is not exactly what you sought.

Comment: ok, finally getting around to doing this and here is the issue: harrymc, the method you suggested is based around the userchrome.css file, which either thunderbird 3 or windows 7 isn't taking for some reason. i've searched pretty thoroughly and can't find any solutions or ideas that have worked. the chrome directory doesn't exist for me, so i tried creating it, but t-bird isn't taking it. any ideas?

Comment: never mind scratch that, got it working. the about:config file also needed to have the mailnews.tags colors edited to match. but here's the remaining problem: all the tags in the message header itself (except one) are transparent instead of colored. i think it might be because the color scheme that guy chose he made it so the background is red, blue, etc and then has it so the text is transparent? not sure